# How to capture audio AND video with FMJ

Tags: java, capture, fmj

I can capture video and audio separately, but the createMergingDataSource method of the javax.media.Manager class in FMJ just throws an UnsupportedOperationException. Is there another way to capture audio and video and encode them in AVI (or any other format).

Comment: You can capture audio without FMJ/JMF etc etc with pure JavaSound. But the video part is really a nightmare. I am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the answer is yes - but only by resorting to native code. Fortunately though, native code and associated jars are freely available for Mac, Windows and Linux which is all most people need.

One such option might be lti-civil: http://lti-civil.org/

VLCJ might also do the trick: http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/